# Bootstrap carousel how do I center the image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap carousel. The problem is my users would be uploading images of different sizes. If the first image is large like this one where the height is more and width is less it would look like this:

http://gyazo.com/33901538d9e2a767b236bc5d48a909bd

But then when the 2nd item is in landscape mode it looks like this:

http://gyazo.com/0f551cc17c70f86e6ae4c51ee97cbb54

This is fine but how do I vertically center the image so it doesn't look horrible as it does now.

Comment: post some code my man, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: My man you can try this jsfiddle. Please see caption 1 image it sticks to the top: http://jsfiddle.net/rdugan/JFBFU/26/ It would be better if it's vertically centered

Comment: i didn't fix it, but i got it closer. http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/JFBFU/311/ **EDIT** maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509043/bootstrap-carousel-how-do-i-center-the-image?noredirect=1#comment37944971_24509043

Comment: It's not of any use since the image stays there only.

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't understand my last answer this is the jsfiddle...

So put the picture in backgroud before and use

```
background-size: cover;
```

like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JFBFU/326/

Comment: Thanks but I want to use img tag not use div and place background there.